# How to reset Iterator on MapReduce Function in Apache Spark

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm a newbie with Apache-Spark. I wanna know how to reset the pointer to Iterator in MapReduce function in Apache Spark so that I wrote

```
Iterator<Tuple2<String,Set<String>>> iter = arg0;
```

but it isn't working. Following is a class implementing MapReduce function in java.

```
class CountCandidates implements Serializable,
    PairFlatMapFunction<Iterator<Tuple2<String,Set<String>>>, Set<String>, Integer>,
    Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>{

    private List<Set<String>> currentCandidatesSet;
    public CountCandidates(final List<Set<String>> currentCandidatesSet) {
        this.currentCandidatesSet = currentCandidatesSet;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Tuple2<Set<String>, Integer>> call(
            Iterator<Tuple2<String, Set<String>>> arg0)
            throws Exception {
        List<Tuple2<Set<String>,Integer>> resultList = 
                new LinkedList<Tuple2<Set<String>,Integer>>();

        for(Set<String> currCandidates : currentCandidatesSet){
            Iterator<Tuple2<String,Set<String>>> iter = arg0;
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Set<String> events = iter.next()._2;
                if(events.containsAll(currCandidates)){
                    Tuple2<Set<String>, Integer> t = 
                            new Tuple2<Set<String>, Integer>(currCandidates,1);
                    resultList.add(t);
                }
            }
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call(Integer arg0, Integer arg1) throws Exception {
        return arg0+arg1;
    }
}
```

If iterator can not be reset in the function how can I iterate the parameter arg0 several times? I already tried some different ways as following code but it is also not working. The following code seems like 'resultList' has too many data than I expected.

```
        while(arg0.hasNext()){
            Set<String> events = arg0.next()._2;
            for(Set<String> currentCandidates : currentCandidatesSet){
                if(events.containsAll(currentCandidates)){
                    Tuple2<Set<String>, Integer> t = 
                            new Tuple2<Set<String>, Integer>(currentCandidates,1);
                    resultList.add(t);
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance for your answer and sorry for my poor english. If you don't understand my question please make a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hadoop iterator could theoretically be reset to the beginning if it was cloneable. Reseting to the beginning in a Mapreduce framework would be acceptable since you would still get to read the file from the beginning getting better overall speed. Reseting the iterator to a random point would be counter to the Mapreduce mind set because it would likely require random access from a file.

There is a ticket in [Hadoop's Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-475) explaining why they chose not to make the iterator cloneable although it does indicate that it is possible that it would be since the values would **not** have to be stored in memory.

Answer (score 2):

An `Iterator` can't be 'reset' in plain Java or Scala, even. That's the nature of an `Iterator`. An `Iterable` is something that can provide you `Iterator`s many times. Your code needs to be rewritten to accept an `Iterable`, if that's what you really want to do.

Comment: I know that 'Iterator' is not resettable but the mapreduce function force me get 'Iterator' object so I want to know how can I solve this problem.

Comment: You can always read the contents of the `Iterator` into a `Collection`, but of course that means you have to hold all of it in memory at once. This may or may not be OK for your use case.

Comment: Are you sure that you can't reset the iterator to the beginning by making multiple copies of `Iterable.iterator` I vaguely remember doing this

Comment: guess not actually [hadoop-475](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-475)

Comment: you're right, @aaronman. the link was very helpful for me to understand why they does not provide clonable. I think it is better to select your answer.